# Ruby on Rails: Renaming model X to Person model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I just renamed my table **Client** to **Person** using this command:

```
class RenameClientsToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :clients, :people
  end
end
```

I carefully renamed all instances and filenames from *client* to *person* and from *clients* to *people*. But for some reason my app won't work anymore. I constantly get errors like this:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: projects.person_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "people" ON "projects"."person_id" = "people"."person_id" WHERE "people"."user_id" = 1
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

Maybe I should re-create the Person model from scratch instead of just renaming it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to rename all your foreign keys from `client_id` to `person_id`, and it looks like you've neglected to do this. In that migration, you'll want to do something like this:

```
class RenameClientsToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :clients, :people
    rename_column :projects, :client_id, :person_id
  end
end
```

Do that for every column that referenced `client_id`.

Comment: OK, thanks. That was a little embarrassing but the foreign keys are fixed now. I am getting a different error now, when trying to create a new person: can't write unknown attribute 'person_id'. For some reason Rails still won't recognize the primary keys.

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer and post a new question if this has led to new problems. Other people might know the answer to your followup question and they won't find it here.